# Find how many connections from a particular user to ActionCable channel there currently are

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I need to track how many connections a user has to an ActionCable channel, so that I know that he, for instance, has two or three browser tabs open, or none at all. This is necessary to understand whether a particular user is offline or online. Is there a way to count number of connections from a particular user to a particular channel?

I've actually implemented a custom solution, where I basically have a counter in Redis which I increment/decrement upon each connect/disconnect. However as of right now it remains rather buggy and it's hard to debug it due to absence of unit testing mechanism for ActionCable. So, I was wondering if there's a "native" reliable way to count user connections.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542817/with-actioncable-is-there-a-way-to-count-how-many-subscribers-from-inside-a-cha/43680487#43680487

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

`ActionCable.server.remote_connections.where(current_user: User.find(1)).count`

that's assuming you're using

`identified_by :current_user` in your `Connection`.

[Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/remote_connections.rb#L13)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This shows how many connections user has to all channels, not a particular channel.

Comment: Does not work anymore: NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for #<ActionCable::RemoteConnections::RemoteConnection:0x005613051a4f50>